# My Mac is running out of power too quickly

Tags: macos, mac, battery

My Mac is pretty new but it's running out of power too quickly.

I tried to check how much energy my open apps were using but I found nothing critical. Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: how quick? which programs are open? specifications?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If so, that’s your problem, and you should use Safari instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: @SteveManson Yes, Chrome is a notorious battery hog, while Apple have done a lot of work on optimising Safari's power use. Switch to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to be methodical about this sort of thing. I don't doubt the advice to switch browser, but you might have other energy hogs.

Use Activity Monitor's Energy tab and whatever applications have a high Avg Energy Impact are your problem. I've just had a look on my iMac and I've been surprised to find that Console.app is second only to Firefox in terms of average energy impact here.